# ¿Por qué mis sockets en nodejs no funcionan?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, socket.io, websocket

Resulta que tengo un servidor en nodejs con http y algo de express:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const io = require('socket.io');

const server = http.createServer(app);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Servidor iniciadio");
})

var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("Nuevo cliente conectado");
})

socket.on('mensaje-cliente', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Y tengo también un cliente:

```
$(function() {
  //socket iniciado
  var socket = io();

  //variables
  var message = $("#chat-message");
  var chat = $("#chat");
  message.focus();

  $("#message-box").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('mensaje-cliente', message.val()); 
  })

});
```

por el cual trabajo con jquery y socket.io.

Mi problema radica en que la conexión de socket no me va bien, no me muestra los mensajes del cliente en consola como le digo al servidor, tampoco me marca un error en consola, simplemente no ocurre ¿Qué hago mal?

Este es mi html por si necesitan checarlo también:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style media="screen">
      #chat {
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 20%;
      }
      #message-box {
        width: 20%;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Muesta los textos del chat -->
    <div class="container">
      <div id="chat">

      </div>
      <!-- Controloes del chat -->
      <form id="message-box">
        <input type="text"  id="chat-message">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
      </form>
    </div>



    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ahi podran ver que tengo tanto a jquery como socket io andando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución y el problema es que el on('connection') del server no tiene que ver con el del socket. Por eso la confusión, así que quedaría más o menos así:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const io = require('socket.io')();

const server = http.createServer(app);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Servidor iniciadio");
})

var sockets = io.listen(server);

sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("Nuevo cliente conectado");

  socket.on('mensaje-cliente', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
})
```